Unable to execute try catch blocks based on element visibility in playwright with typescript
I have a scenario to automate wherein if I see that the title of the page is "Example title", then I can mark the test as passed.
Else, if that is not possible, I have to click on something else that is available on the page and then verify if the title is "Example title".
My code:
I tried using the try catch block, but somehow always get the timeout error. Following is the code snippet
try {
    await expect.soft(page).toHaveTitle("Example title",{ timeout: 30000 })
  }
  catch (error){
    await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'here' }).click();
    await expect.soft(page).toHaveTitle("Example title",{ timeout: 30000 })
  }

What I expected was that script would execute the try block first, and when the timeout error occured it would be caught and the catch block would then be executed.
But the code never reaches the catch block. Instead I get the following error:
Error:

Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded.

Error: expect(locator).toHaveTitle(expected)

Locator: locator(':root')
Expected string: "Example title"
Received string: "Some Count Exceeded"
Call log:
  - expect.soft.toHaveTitle with timeout 30000ms
  - waiting for locator(':root')
  -   locator resolved to <html>…</html>
  -   unexpected value "dfretgrt"
  ...



>  19 |
      20 |   try {
    > 21 |     await expect.soft(page).toHaveTitle("Example title",{ timeout: 30000 })
         |                             ^
      22 |
      23 |   }
      24 |   catch (error){


That try/catch will never work as an assertion doesn't throw an error. It will just pass or fail that test.
You could try testing the .count() on the locator and if it is 0, perform your click and then do the assertion.

@AutomationAndy
So I can't really make use of the page title in this scenario, instead I should make use of some web element on the page. Is that right?

Even if this pattern worked, your test would take up to a minute to run! Your team will hate you every time they run CI. Branches and non-determinism are not good in tests. Tests that sometimes fail and sometimes don't can't really be trusted. Please provide more details and preferably the actual page under test, and your full test code. Does clicking the link trigger a nav, and using the title as a stand-in for .toHaveUrl? Are you trying to make up for flakiness elsewhere? I'd suggest always clicking.

Use "OR" locator.
Creates a locator that matches either of the two locators.This can be used in variety of conditions including yours.
Usage Example
Consider a scenario where you'd like to click on a "New email" button, but sometimes a security settings dialog shows up instead. In this case, you can wait for either a "New email" button, or a dialog and act accordingly.
const newEmail = page.getByRole('button', { name: 'New' });
const dialog = page.getByText('Confirm security settings');
await expect(newEmail.or(dialog)).toBeVisible();
if (await dialog.isVisible())
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Dismiss' }).click();
await newEmail.click();

Reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-or
